# rustc-serialize custom enum decoding

Tags: json, rust

I have a JSON structure where one of the fields of a struct could be either an object, or that object's ID in the database. Let's say the document looks like this with both possible formats of the struct:

```
[
   {
      "name":"pebbles",
      "car":1
   },
   {
      "name":"pebbles",
      "car":{
         "id":1,
         "color":"green"
      }
   }
]
```

I'm trying to figure out the best way to implement a custom decoder for this. So far, I've tried a few different ways, and I'm currently stuck here:

```
extern crate rustc_serialize;

use rustc_serialize::{Decodable, Decoder, json};

#[derive(RustcDecodable, Debug)]
struct Car {
  id: u64,
  color: String
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum OCar {
  Id(u64),
  Car(Car)
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Person {
  name: String,
  car: OCar
}

impl Decodable for Person {
  fn decode<D: Decoder>(d: &mut D) -> Result<Person, D::Error> {
    d.read_struct("root", 2, |d| {
      let mut car: OCar;

      // What magic must be done here to get the right OCar?

      /* I tried something akin to this:
      let car = try!(d.read_struct_field("car", 0, |r| {
        let r1 = Car::decode(r);
        let r2 = u64::decode(r);

        // Compare both R1 and R2, but return code for Err() was tricky
      }));
      */

      /* And this got me furthest */
      match d.read_struct_field("car", 0, u64::decode) {
        Ok(x) => {
          car = OCar::Id(x);
        },
        Err(_) => {
          car = OCar::Car(try!(d.read_struct_field("car", 0, Car::decode)));
        }
      }


      Ok(Person {
        name: try!(d.read_struct_field("name", 0, Decodable::decode)),
        car: car
      })
    })
  }
}

fn main() {
  // Vector of both forms
  let input = "[{\"name\":\"pebbles\",\"car\":1},{\"name\":\"pebbles\",\"car\":{\"id\":1,\"color\":\"green\"}}]";

  let output: Vec<Person> = json::decode(&input).unwrap();

  println!("Debug: {:?}", output);
}
```

The above panics with an EOL which is a sentinel value rustc-serialize uses on a few of its error enums. Full line is

```
thread '<main>' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: EOF', src/libcore/result.rs:785
```

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`rustc-serialize`, or at least its JSON decoder, doesn't support that use case. If you look at the [implementation of `read_struct_field`](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustc-serialize/blob/08503bd31d02deb53e1c799bfd362b83708da3f6/src/json.rs#L2245-L2271) (or any other method), you can see why: it uses a stack, but when it encounters an error, it doesn't bother to restore the stack to its original state, so when you try to decode the same thing differently, the decoder is operating on an inconsistent stack, eventually leading to an unexpected EOF value.

I would recommend you look into [Serde](https://serde-rs.github.io/serde/serde/index.html) instead. Deserializing in Serde is different: instead of telling the decoder what type you're expecting, and having no clear way to recover if a value is of the wrong type, Serde calls into a [visitor](https://serde-rs.github.io/serde/serde/de/trait.Visitor.html) that can handle any of the types that Serde supports in the way it wants. This means that Serde will call different methods on the visitor depending on the actual type of the value it parsed. For example, we can handle integers to return an `OCar::Id` and objects to return an `OCar::Car`.

Here's a full example:

```
#![feature(custom_derive, plugin)]
#![plugin(serde_macros)]

extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_json;

use serde::de::{Deserialize, Deserializer, Error, MapVisitor, Visitor};
use serde::de::value::MapVisitorDeserializer;

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Car {
    id: u64,
    color: String
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum OCar {
    Id(u64),
    Car(Car),
}

struct OCarVisitor;

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Person {
    name: String,
    car: OCar,
}

impl Deserialize for OCar {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: &mut D) -> Result<Self, D::Error> where D: Deserializer {
        deserializer.deserialize(OCarVisitor)
    }
}

impl Visitor for OCarVisitor {
    type Value = OCar;

    fn visit_u64<E>(&mut self, v: u64) -> Result<Self::Value, E> where E: Error {
        Ok(OCar::Id(v))
    }

    fn visit_map<V>(&mut self, visitor: V) -> Result<Self::Value, V::Error> where V: MapVisitor {
        Ok(OCar::Car(try!(Car::deserialize(&mut MapVisitorDeserializer::new(visitor)))))
    }
}

fn main() {
    // Vector of both forms
    let input = "[{\"name\":\"pebbles\",\"car\":1},{\"name\":\"pebbles\",\"car\":{\"id\":1,\"color\":\"green\"}}]";

    let output: Vec<Person> = serde_json::from_str(input).unwrap();

    println!("Debug: {:?}", output);
}
```

Output:

```
Debug: [Person { name: "pebbles", car: Id(1) }, Person { name: "pebbles", car: Car(Car { id: 1, color: "green" }) }]
```

---

Cargo.toml:

```
[dependencies]
serde = "0.7"
serde_json = "0.7"
serde_macros = "0.7"
```

Comment: Very good answer! I did noticed the stack while digging though but didn't spend the time to check how pulling data out multiple times or throwing errors would affect it. One problem though: This forces me into nightly mode because of serde_macros. Is there a way around that?

Comment: See [Using Serde with Stable Rust and serde_codegen](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde#using-serde-with-stable-rust-and-serde_codegen).